# Com preencher um spinner com um campo de um objeto

Tags: android, spinners

Tenho um *Spinner* na minha *Activity*, preciso fazer com que seus itens sejam os nomes (campo) de um *ArrayList* de objetos, e que quando selecionado, me seja retornado o id do mesmo para poder realizar uma nova operação.

Por exemplo:

Meu objeto contato

```
public class Contato {

    String nome;
    int id;
    //getters e setters
}
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, porém no *Spinner* é exibido somente o endereço do objeto na memória do aplicativo.
Como posso fazer com que seja exibido o nome obtido de cada objeto no *Spinner* e seja retornado o id do mesmo?

```
// Uma lista contendo os objetos
ArrayList<Contact> contactlist= new ArrayList<Contact>();
contactlist.add("Gabe");
contactlist.add("Mark");
contactlist.add("Bill");
contactlist.add("Steve");

// Array Adapter que é definido como adapter do spinner
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contactlist);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma ideal será escrever um Adapter para o efeito.

Não querendo ter esse "trabalho" e usando o ArrayAdapter, uma forma expedita é tirar partido de como o ArrayAdapter funciona.

O ArrayAdapter usa o método `toString()` da classe usada como item do ArrayList para obter o valor a apresentar.
O valor que o método `toString()` retornar é aquele que o *Spinner* apresentará.

Na classe *Contato* faça o *Override* do método `toString()` de forma a retornar o campo `nome`:

```
public class Contato {

    String nome;
    int id;
    //getters e setters

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Para obter o `id` do Contato selecionado faça:

```
Contato contato = (Contato)spinner.getSelectedItem();
int id = contato.id;
```

Ou de forma mais directa:

```
int id = ((Contato)spinner.getSelectedItem()).id;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.