# Custom Spinner mostrando resource e não texto

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Estou com problemas para configurar um spinner customizado em minha aplicação.
Segue abaixo imagem de como ele aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código:

Adapter.java

```
public class ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProfissionalCategoria>   {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista;

    public ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista) {
        super(context, 0, lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ProfissionalCategoria itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.profissional_cat_item_spinner,null);
        final View layout = convertView;

        TextView textView_categoriaNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_profissionalCatItemSpinner);
        textView_categoriaNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Activity onde deverá ser mostrado o spinner:

```
this.spinner_profissionalCategoria = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_profissionalCategoria);

ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista = new DAOProfissionalCategoria(getActivity()).buscarCategoria(profissionalCategoria);
ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter profissionalCategoriaAdapter = new ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter(getActivity(),lista);
profissionalCategoriaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner_profissionalCategoria.setAdapter(profissionalCategoriaAdapter);
spinner_profissionalCategoria.setPrompt("Escolha");
```

Classe ProfissionalCategoria

```
public class ProfissionalCategoria { 
  private int autoId; 
  private String nome; 

  public int getAutoId() { 
    return autoId; 
  }

  public void setAutoId(int autoId) { 
    this.autoId = autoId; 
  }

  public String getNome() {
    return nome; 
  } 

  public void setNome(String nome) { 
    this.nome = nome; 
  }
}
```

Acredito que as informações necessárias estão aí.

**Solução:**

Criei um método no DAO para buscar os dados e retornar com um tipo diferente, veja:

Método anterior:

```
public ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> buscarCategoria(ProfissionalCategoria profissionalCategoria) {
    ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"autoid", "nome"};

    Cursor cursor = this.db.query("ProfissionalCategoria",colunas,null,null,null,null,"nome");

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            profissionalCategoria = new ProfissionalCategoria();
            profissionalCategoria.setAutoId(cursor.getInt(0));
            profissionalCategoria.setNome(cursor.getString(1));

            lista.add(profissionalCategoria);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();

    }
    db.close();
    return lista;
}
```

Novo método:

```
public List<String> buscarCatSpinner(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"autoid", "nome"};
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query("ProfissionalCategoria",colunas,null,null,null,null,"nome");

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1));//adding 2nd column data
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return list;
}
```

E na activity onde mostra o spinner:

```
DAOProfissionalCategoria db = new DAOProfissionalCategoria(getActivity());
    List<String> labels = db.buscarCatSpinner();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_profissionalCategoria.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Obrigado pela ajuda atenção de todos.

Comment: Na verdade ele parece estar mostrando o nome do objeto, e não o valor da propriedade retornada por itemPosicao.getNome(). Tente colocar um BreakPoint e debuggar ali a função GetView o que está sendo carregado no itemPosicao.

Comment: Olá Celso, então, no breakpoint ele mostra o seguinte:
Lista: size=4, position=0
Pelo visto está carregando os dados da tabela corretamente, tanto que quando seleciono alguma opção no spinner ele mostra depois que clico.

Comment: Davi, se você encontrou solução diferente das respostas, você deve publicar como resposta ao invés de adicionar na pergunta, assim, sua solução ficará mais evidente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pequena introdução ao Spinner.**

O [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) é composto por duas *Views*: a *Selected item view*, que mostra o item selecionado e a *drop-down view*, onde são mostrados todos os itens e que permite a selecção de um deles.

Para obter cada uma das *Views*, a classe *Spinner* recorre aos métodos [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) e [getDropDownView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)), da implementação da interface [SpinnerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html)(normalmente um [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)) que lhe é passada através do método [setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)).

O [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) implementa esses dois métodos no pressuposto que as *Views* usadas têm um *TextView* com `id = android.R.id.text1`(em XML:`android:id="@android:id/text1"`).
O *TextView* é preenchido com o resultado da chamada ao método `toString()` de cada objecto do *array* ou *ArrayList* passado ao construtor.

Quando estes pressupostos não são satisfeitos ou não podem ser resolvidos usando o construtor [ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)), é necessário criar um *custom adapter*.
Nesse *adapter* deve ser feito o *override* desse dois métodos de forma a retornarem as *views* correctamente preenchidas.

**O seu problema.**

Apesar de estar a utilizar um *custom adapter* ele não faz o *override* do método `getDropDownView()`.
O *adapter* terá assim o comportamento por defeito que é utilizar o método `toString()` para obter o texto a apresentar na *drop-down view*.

Como *ProfissionalCategoria* não faz o seu *override*, é usado o método da classe base(*Object*) que retorna uma string composta pelo nome da classe, da qual o objecto é uma instância, o símbolo `@`, seguido da representação hexadecimal do código *hash* do *objecto*.

**Como resolver.**

Utilize uma destas 3 soluções.

1. Mantenha o seu *adapter* como está e faça o *override* do método `toString()` da classe *ProfissionalCategoria* desta forma:

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return nome;
   }
   ```
2. Faça o *override* do método `getDropDownView()` do seu *adapter*

   ```
   public class ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProfissionalCategoria>   {

       private Context context;
       private ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista;

       public ProfissionalCategoriaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista) {
           super(context, 0, lista);
           this.context = context;
           this.lista = lista;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
           return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)
       }

       @Override
       public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
           return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)
       }

       //Método auxiliar para criar a view, já que se usa a mesma view nos dois métodos
       private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
           final ProfissionalCategoria itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);

           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.profissional_cat_item_spinner,null);
           final View layout = convertView;

           TextView textView_categoriaNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_profissionalCatItemSpinner);
           textView_categoriaNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

           return convertView;
       }
   }
   ```

   Deve eliminar a linha:

   ```
   profissionalCategoriaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   ```
3. Como usa uma *View* apenas com um *TextView*, *esqueça o seu adapter*, faça o *override* do método `toString()` da classe *ProfissionalCategoria* e utilize um *ArrayAdapter*

   ```
   ArrayList<ProfissionalCategoria> lista = new DAOProfissionalCategoria(getActivity()).buscarCategoria(profissionalCategoria);
   ArrayAdapter<ProfissionalCategoria> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProfissionalCategoria>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista);
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinner_profissionalCategoria.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   ```

**Perguntas relacionadas:**

[Spinner para selecionar Cor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68590/2541)
[Com preencher um spinner com um campo de um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108406/2541)