# Fazer o metodo ToString() retornar dois campos separadamente de um objeto tipado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Preciso fazer com que a função ToString retorne o tamanho e a cor separadamente, pois estou preenchendo um spinner com eles. Um spinner é preenchido com as cores e outro com o tamanho. Porem se eu colocar:

```
public String ToString(){
  return cor + tamanho;
}
```

Os dois spinner sao preenchido com a cor e o tamanho juntos...

Objeto:

```
public class Cores {
    private String cor;
    private String tamanho;

    public String getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public void setTamanho(String tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }

    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

}
```

Comment: O `ToString()`não foi feito para isto, crie um método diferente pra sua necessidade específica, não use um método genérico que já deve atender outra necessidade.

Comment: Tem que implementar um Adapter para cada um. No *override* do método `getDropDownView()` obtenha e use o campo que pretende mostrar. Relacionado [Custom Spinner mostrando resource e não texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143340/custom-spinner-mostrando-resource-e-n%c3%a3o-texto/143380#143380)

Answer (score 2):

Reforçando o comentário do @Maniero, você deve criar métodos específicos para obter essas propriedades separadamente. O padrão de métodos getters deve ser suficiente para atender essa necessidade, veja o código:

```java
public class MeuObjeto {
  private String cor;
  private String tamanho;

  public String getCor() {
    return this.cor;
  }

  public String getTamanho() {
    return this.tamanho;
  }

  public String getCorTamanho() {
    return this.cor + " " + this.tamanho;
  }
}
```

Os métodos `getCor()` e `getTamanho()` retornam apenas o dado de acordo com o nome do método. Já o `getCorTamanho()` retorna a concatenação de ambos, podendo ser formatado como você desejar.

Comment: Na primeira tentativa, eu usava o getCor(), como vc esta sugerindo, porem em vez dele me retornar o valor da cor (por exemplo "vermelho "). Ele me retorna o pack name...
Por exemplo :
com.example.exemplo.exemplo.model.cliente.Cores@9e62....

Comment: @Daniel Neste caso edite a pergunta e coloque o código da sua classe `MeuObjeto` se puder

Comment: Coloquei o objeto la

Comment: Se você está recebendo o package name, é porquê `cor` é um objeto - e a representação padrão de um objeto em String, é seu package name (com outras informações que não vem ao caso agora). Edite a pergunta e adicione **todo** o código envolvendo as cores, assim podemos te ajudar de forma mais eficiente.